# Are snide remarks allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about [dots on jerseys](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/20231) and got the following comment:

[image: comment]

Funny thing is, I saw the photo on a news website and a headline about how the Orioles were wearing dots (admittedly, I didn't read that article, which would have brought me to my answer, but not everyone knows the headquarters for The National Federation of the Blind is located in Baltimore).

Anyway, I find the remark to be sarcastic and snide in nature. Is this allowed here?

I get it, I should've read the article, but not everyone knows everything about a particular sport like some would have you believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not allowed as it is a clear violation of our [Code of Conduct](https://sports.stackexchange.com/conduct). I've removed the comment; apologies that this happened.